# After installing Anaconda - trying to run it stuck on "adding featured channels"

Tags: anaconda

I download and install Anaconda for python 2.7 on windows 10. Trying to open Anaconda navigator get stuck on "adding featured channels" forever as shown in the following image:[image]

Anyone know what the problem can be?

Answer (score 2):

Only uninstall anaconda and install again fix this problem.

If you have this problem don't waste your time. Give it 2 minutes and if it is stuck uninstall and reinstall anaconda will save your time.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to get around this by running Anaconda as administrator in windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but for python3. This was the solution.

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
conda update conda
anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 0):

Open command line (Windows) or Terminal (MacOS/Linux) and run:

`conda deactivate`

`conda update anaconda-navigator`

Then open Anaconda Navigator like normal.

Pulled from docs:
https://docs.anaconda.com/navigator/update-navigator/